# Image does not display when uploaded - Magento 2.4.3

Tags: php, magento, magento2, gd2

I get the following error when I upload an image in magento 2.4.3

Does not display on front end or in product grid

`[2022-05-28 17:46:30] main.CRITICAL: Warning: imageinterlace() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 201 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Warning: imageinterlace() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 201 at /vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it by replacing the folder completely `/vendor/magento/framework/Image/`